# Can you run in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a lot of people on SMP that seem to go faster than me when playing. Did I miss a run button that I'm not aware in the game?

Comment: Do you know what mods are installed on your server as they is no way to move faster in vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of **Beta 1.8**, you can sprint by double-tapping the forward key (<kbd>W</kbd> by default). This seems to be unlimited, as long as you don't let go of the button and don't run into anything. Hitting a mob while sprinting will also cause you to stop sprinting, and send the mob flying.

Your food meter drains a lot quicker while sprinting, and when it's down to 3 pieces of meat or less, you can't sprint at all.

---

> **Old answer, preserved for posterity:**
>   Not currently, no. The people you saw were probably either lagging (and their delayed position update caused them to look like they're running) or using speedhacks.
>
> Although, [notch has toyed with a sprint mechanic](https://plus.google.com/116872576248355504859/posts/i8NKiBJbRZ6), so it's possible that this will be added in a future update.

Comment: On a related note, if you want to get from place to place more quickly, mine carts are a great way to get around, and you can use nether portals for a shortcut. Just watch out for Ghasts.

Answer (score -3):

You can run, but it's called sprinting: tap <kbd>w</kbd> twice. However, I couldn't get it to work (but it works for my cousin).

Comment: Hi Angel, this duplicates [what was already posted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/28380/3389).